# Whether heartbleed is attaked while we are using heartbeat with apache(httpd)?

Tags: heartbleed

We are using heartbeat for high availability of httpd. In httpd we are using openssl of version 0.9.8 but about heartbeat i dont much about that but while search in google some sites are sayong that if u use heartbeat we are affected with heartbleed. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [the Heartbleed website](http://heartbleed.com/):

> OpenSSL 0.9.8 branch is NOT vulnerable